# DocumentDB Range and Hash index

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a requirment for the following search :

`SELECT * FROM root WHERE root.parentPath = 'value'`

and

`SELECT * FROM root WHERE STARTSWITH(root.parentPath,'value')`

With index type `hash` the first query runs fast and the second query requires a scan so goes very slow.

With index type 'range` the first query is slow and the second query fast.

In order to support both querys would I need to store the data twice? When I try to add the index again I get the following error `Duplicate indexes specified for the path`

-- edit

I have added the following XML to the settings area of the index, it works with the Range or the Hash but not both.

```
{
    "path": "/parentPath/?",
    "indexes": [
        {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "String",
            "precision": 3
        },
        {
            "kind": "Hash",
            "dataType": "String",
            "precision": 3
        },
        {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "Number",
            "precision": -1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your index script?

Comment: @RafatSarosh updated, is it a `Portal Issue`? wonder if it will work via script, something to try Monday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, Hash index should not have query performance advantage over Range index. In some cases, and due to index collisions, Hash index might seem to improve the query performance. The recommendation here is to stick w/ Range index and precision -1 for all indexed paths.

To check whether or not the query is suffering from index collisions (low index utilization), retrieve the query execution metrics as per this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query-metrics#query-execution-metrics

Comment: looks like it was an issue with my precision, the performance for the search with a range index is acceptable ( 34.48 for Hash vs 36.92 for Range). Thanks for the input, I blame copy and paste :)